# How to write a pow() function to handle pow(2, 48) without getting infinity (overflow) in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

long double abs(long double num){
        if (num>=0)
                return num;
        else
                return -num;
}

long double pow(long double val, long double given_exp){

        long double res = val;
        long double exp = abs(given_exp);

        for (; exp > 1; exp--){
                res *= res;
        }

        if (given_exp > 0)
                return res;
        else
                return 1/res;
}

int main(){
        std::cout << pow(2, 1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << pow(2, -1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << pow(2, 48) << std::endl;
}
```

This is the second exercise in Lippman's 2nd edition.
Right now, the last line prints inf. How do I modify this function to prevent overflow?

Comment: I think you meant `res *= given_exp`, not `res *= res`.

Comment: It's not that it overflows, it's because your code is wrong. Try to [debug it yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (print values, run in a debugger) for some small values (say, 2^3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
                res *= res;
```

is wrong. It will calculate `res` times `res` in each iteration and make the number very big.

It should be

```
                res *= val;
```

Comment: In particular, `res *= res` means it calculates something like 2^(2^n). (Or, to be exact, it looks to be 2^(2^(n-1)) for positive n here.)